# How to implement XMP preset filters on images in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, xmp

I have a `XMP` file and need to apply `XMP` filters on an image. I have converted it into `CFData` but not able to read dictionary or array format. I have researched about `XMP` file in iOS, but I don't think it can implemented by changing meta data of image.

My XMP file can be downloaded from link below:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rUcjkT5rcV_rG89blTLJfvL9AgOvmWUX/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Method :-** You can convert your XMP file to json file and apply filters on image.

If you want to convert your XMP into json then can use `python-xmp-toolkit` or my [convertXMPToJson](https://github.com/macvinod/XMP-To-Json).

If you are using my python file then just need to set path on your terminal and run below command.

```
python convertXMPToJson.py XMP/your_XMP_file_Name.xmp json/your_Json_file_Name.json
```

It convert your xmp file to json file and you can apply CIFilter or write custom filter using CIKernel, Metal.

> Sample CIFilter

```
let imgFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIExposureAdjust")
imgFilter?.setValue(value, forKey: kCIInputEVKey)
filter.setValue(image, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
guard let filteredImage = filter.value(forKey: kCIOutputImageKey) else { return image }
```

You can find sample filter at [here](https://github.com/macvinod/Image-Filters).

Lot of CIFilter available in `Core Image`. You can find other CIFilter at [here](https://cifilter.io/).